# Push a view from a nib file using a right navigation bar button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

As described in the title, i would like to push a view, from a known NIB, using a button on the navigation bar. I'm working on a UINavigationController app.

I already added the right button in IB and i linked it to the method that is in the RootViewController

I have searched everywhere but I couldn't find a way to do this method...

```
-(IBAction)addItems:(id)sender 
{
    ?
}
```

I also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086789/loading-a-table-view-nib-after-button-push), but it isn't working either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
-(IBAction)addItems:(id)sender 
{
    CustomController *controller = [[CustomController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
}
```

Where

1. `CustomController` name of your custom controller class.
2. `@"CustomController"` name of your xib file

Comment: That was exactly what i was looking for. I still have some errors, but I'll work on that. Thank m8!

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the view from nib file, then try this..

```
NSArray* nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"QPickOneView"
                                                  owner:self
                                                options:nil];

UIView* myView = [ nibViews objectAtIndex: 0];

self.view = myView;
```

If you want to push a ViewController..Then go with the Nekto's Answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the Nekto's Answer was more useful.